# Mapping Parent Model To Children Models Using AutoMapper 7 / C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a hierarchy of parent > children models and DTO using C# and AutoMapper 7 in a .Net Core 3 project. I am having problems mapping the parent model to the lowest child DTO.

**The models involved look like this:**

*Parent Model #1:*

```
    public class ParentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MainElement> MainElements { get; set; }

    public ParentElementModel()
    {
        MainElements = new Collection<MainElement>();
    }
}
```

*Parent Model #2 (This is actually a .Net Core Identity User but simplified for this):*

```
public class ParentUserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

*Parent Model #3 Which is the MainElement Model which includes a CreatedBy that is of type of the ParentUserModel above:*

```
    public class MainElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ParentUserModel CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

**The DTO to map are:**

*Most parent DTO:*

```
    public class ParentModelForReturnDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MainElementForParentModelDto> MainElements { get; set; }
}
```

*The ICollection DTO model:*

```
    public class MainElementForParentModelDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public UserCreatorForMainElementDto CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

*The DTO for the CreatedBy ParentUserModel that lacks the OtherData which would be sensitive info I can't include:*

```
    public class UserCreatorForMainElementDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**My problem is that the ParentModelForReturnDto's MainElementForParentModelDto's CreatedBy is coming back null when I want it to have the CreatedBy ParentUserModel's Id and Username**

Here are my related mappings that don't fully map it:

```
CreateMap<ParentModel, ParentModelForReturnDto>();
CreateMap<MainElement, MainElementForParentModelDto>();
CreateMap<ParentUserModel, UserCreatorForMainElementDto >();
```

**Can anyone please help me figure out how to map these so that the CreatedBy returns of type UserCreatorForMainElementDto and not null?**

I believe the error to be in the mapping from MainElement to MainElementForParentModelDto but I am unsure. I have been trying for awhile to figure this out.

Any questions I can clarify. Tried to take out the unnecessary while keeping enough. Thank you to anyone who can help!

Edit:

The above mappings are using Profile.

Here is what I am mapping in my controller:

```
var parentModelFromRepo = _context.GetParent(name)
var parentToReturn = _mapper.Map<ParentModelForReturnDto>(parentModelFromRepo);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `parentModelFromRepo` is populated with all related data needed?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, if I replace ICollection<MainElementForParentModelDto> with ICollection<MainElement> then everything about the user is returned including all the OtherData I don't want.

Comment: @IvanStoev That is where my deduction that my inability is somewhere in the use of MainElementForParentModelDto because if I let everything be returned about the MainElement including the full user without use of that DTO then everything is returned but everything is too sensitive.

Comment: @IvanStoev And to fully answer your question, in order for that to happen parentModelFromRepo must have that data within it if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm asking because there is `entity-framework` tag, so one of the possible reasons of having `null` destination data is to have `null` **source** data (which is not so unusual with EF, and especially with EF Core). The mappings are too simple in order to suspect AutoMapper. Can you provide repro code not involving EF, e.g. `var parentModelFromRepo = new ParentModel { /* sample data */ };` having `MainElement`s with `CreatedBy` populated and disappears after mapping?

Comment: @IvanStoev I understand. I don't think it can be null data because when I use the full MainElement model in the ICollection such as ICollection<MainElement> all the data is there. Imo this proves that the data is not null, and disappears / does not map properly when ICollection<MainElementForParentModelDto> is used.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just changed the ParentModelForReturnDto to say ICollection<MainElement> and the CreatedBy field is populated just populated with too much. This proves that the data is not null I think.

Comment: @IvanStoev Also the models are more complex than what I have put here, but there is definitely something wrong about how I am doing it on a basic level so I left out the majority of the fields.

Comment: I ran these mapping on my own and it went smoothly without a single error. There is definitely something wrong in your code. Check the names, look for typos, that kind of thing.